# Extjs 4.1 timefield returning 2008 as the year

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs5, timefield

I have created a simple application using extjs `timefield`. Here is the code & [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdazU/1536/):

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Time Card',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'timefield',
        id: 'in',
        fieldLabel: 'Time In',
        //minValue: '6:00 AM',
        //maxValue: '8:00 PM',
        format: 'H:i',
        increment: 30,
        anchor: '100%'
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'click',
        handler: function(){
           alert(Ext.getCmp('in').getValue());
           console.log(Ext.getCmp('in').getValue());
        }
   }]
});
```

**Questions/Issues:**

1. When I use getValue() it returns `Tue Jan 01 2008 01:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)` . **I am not sure why it is returning 2008 as the year?**
2. Is there way a to capture timezone information ?

Comment: Looks buggy. You should set the date part by yourself.

Comment: Timefield aswell as datefield actual value is date object and, as Alexandex mention in his answer, its initial date set to 1/1/2008. If you want to get time you can use `Ext.Date.format(Ext.getCmp('in').getValue(), 'H:i')` or set `submitFormat: 'H:i'` and use `Ext.getCmp('in').getSubmitValue()` or just use `Ext.getCmp('in').getRawValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

The source of `timefield` contains

```
/**
 * @private
 * This is the date to use when generating time values in the absence of either minValue
 * or maxValue.  Using the current date causes DST issues on DST boundary dates, so this is an
 * arbitrary "safe" date that can be any date aside from DST boundary dates.
 */
initDate: '1/1/2008',
initDateParts: [2008, 0, 1],
```

You could override these properties, although they are marked private, but I would not recommend it. I would recommend to use a datefield and a timefield and then calculate a date with time from that.

JavaScript does not support time zones, they only support UTC and Local. ExtJS does not support time zones either. If you need arbitrary time zones, you could have a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get correct date in `renderer` function by doing something similar to this:

```
renderTimeField: function(time) {
    var ndate = new Date(),
        tmin = time.getMinutes(),
        thour = time.getHours();

    return new Date(ndate.setHours(thour, tmin, 0, 0));
},
```